# Is this the right definition for a covariant derivative on a principal bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

Let $P \rightarrow M$ be a smooth principal $G$-bundle. Notation: use $\Gamma$ to denote global (smooth) sections of a bundle. Also, $G$ acts on the left on $P$.

I can't seem to find a specific definition of a covariant derivative on $P$ (though definitions of connections abound), so I was wondering if the following definition makes sense?

---

Definition: Let's say a function $\nabla : \Gamma(TM) \times \Gamma(P) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(M\to\mathrm{Lie}G)$, written $(X,s) \mapsto \nabla_X s$,
is a *covariant derivative* on $P$ if:

(1) $\nabla$ is $C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$-linear in the $\Gamma(TM)$ argument, i.e. $\nabla_X s$ is $C^\infty(M)$-linear in $X$; and

(2) for $g : M \rightarrow G$ smooth, for $s \in \Gamma(TM)$, for $X \in \Gamma(TM)$, we have
$$
\nabla_X(gs) = \mathrm{Ad}_g(\nabla_X s) + 
\theta_G(dg(X))
$$
where $\theta_G$ is the Maurer-Cartan form on $G$.

---

Would the above be the right definition of a covariant derivative on $P$? Is there a source which describes this in detail?

Comment: Covariant derivatives are usually defined on sections of *associated bundles* of $P$, not on sections of $P$ itself. Kobayashi and Nomizu, Volume I, Chapter III has a good discussion of this.

Comment: Right, but I am wondering if there is a notion of covariant derivative we can define on the bundle, and then given a $G$ representation, we can induce a covariant derivative on the associated bundle, obtained from the one on the principal bundle.

Comment: How would a "covariant derivative" on sections of $P$ induce a covariant derivative on sections of an associated bundle? By contrast, it's well known how a connection on $P$ induces a covariant derivative on sections of an associated bundle. I guess the main objection to your proposal is that there's no natural way of adding sections of $P$, so any "covariant derivative" $\nabla_X$ you define won't be linear in the sections (since this becomes a meaningless notion). And linearity is usually a fundamental property you want when defining derivatives.

Comment: Well, I think a principal-bundle covariant derivative would be (constant) G-equivariant, instead of linear, in the sections of P. Also, here we could take the "difference" of principal bundle fiber elements q-p as the g taking p to q; and this can be differentiated, valued in the Lie alg of G.

Comment: Also, I would like parallel transport in $P$ to be defined by a differential equation $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}(\tilde{\gamma}) =0$, where the equation is valued in LieG.